# Ignite spring data @query does not work with delete queries like cache#query()

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I see that delete queries placed in Ignite spring data's @query (org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.Query) does not work analogous to executing them via cache#query() & instead tries to do the query rewriting to get keys in a sub query incorrectly causing it to fail with invalid sql error by H2 engine. Below is an example,

**Spring Data @Query**

```
@Query("delete from EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ?")
void deleteEmpByEmpNoAndEName(final Integer empno, final String ename);
```

**Fails with below error**

```
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""EMPS"".""EMP""._KEY, ""EMPS"".""EMP""._VAL FROM ""EMPS"".""EMP"" WHERE DELETE FROM[*] EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? "; SQL statement:
SELECT "EMPS"."EMP"._KEY, "EMPS"."EMP"._VAL FROM "EMPS"."EMP" WHERE delete from EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? [42000-195]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:803)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:342)
    at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.query.IgniteRepositoryQuery.execute(IgniteRepositoryQuery.java:117)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.deleteEmpByEmpNoAndEName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.deleteEmpByEmpNoAndEName(Unknown Source)
    at com.brocade.dcm.service.MultiNodeReplicationTestService.deleteEmp(MultiNodeReplicationTestService.java:99)
    at com.brocade.dcm.service.MultiNodeReplicationTestService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bbb827bc.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
    at com.brocade.dcm.service.MultiNodeReplicationTestService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62a0e265.deleteEmp(<generated>)
    at com.brocade.dcm.controller.MultiNodeReplicationTestController.deleteEmp(MultiNodeReplicationTestController.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""EMPS"".""EMP""._KEY, ""EMPS"".""EMP""._VAL FROM ""EMPS"".""EMP"" WHERE DELETE FROM[*] EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? "; SQL statement:
SELECT "EMPS"."EMP"._KEY, "EMPS"."EMP"._VAL FROM "EMPS"."EMP" WHERE delete from EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? [42000-195]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatementAndCaches(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2150)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.parseAndSplit(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1915)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.querySqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1753)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSql(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1554)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$6.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2192)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$6.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2190)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2601)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryDistributedSql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2189)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySql(GridQueryProcessor.java:2170)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:788)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ""EMPS"".""EMP""._KEY, ""EMPS"".""EMP""._VAL FROM ""EMPS"".""EMP"" WHERE DELETE FROM[*] EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? "; SQL statement:
SELECT "EMPS"."EMP"._KEY, "EMPS"."EMP"._VAL FROM "EMPS"."EMP" WHERE delete from EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ? [42000-195]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:191)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:533)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:260)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:573)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:514)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepare0(IgniteH2Indexing.java:517)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:485)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:452)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatementAndCaches(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2132)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

**Same via cache#query()**

```
gnition.ignite().cache("EmpCache").query((new SqlFieldsQuery("delete from EMPS.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ? AND ENAME = ?").setArgs(empno, "Neo")));
```

This executes properly (i presume on the server node) & deletes the entry.

Shouldn't both work the same way? Is it a bug in Ignite spring data implementation or am i doing something incorrect..appreciate your feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Try to use DELETE in the upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete and update statements should be supported in latest versions. But there is a known bug with the case of keyword. Could you try to replace "delete" by "DELETE" and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we support DELETE in queries.

You should use `IgniteRepository.delete(key)`.